How to close/normalised the exsi web console?
enter image description here
I have viewing the VMware host from within a VM hosted on it.
Below is the silly step I done:

Remote to the host hosted by VM
Open the vmware exsi web client and view the console (viewing itself)
I have doing it at first screen, and it prompt second screen, can only control in the second screen.
I noticed there is something close button at right top corner of second screen, but after I clicked there is nothing happen.
Opened another console in the second screen and it prompt third screen, can only control in the third screen.

And the screen became more and more smaller...
Have tried to restart the host.
Hope anyone can help...

You can use powercli to run a command on the VM, like Invoke-VMScript -VM $vm -ScriptText "taskkill /f /ia chrome.exe" or disconnect that second session, like so: https://williamlam.com/2022/06/how-to-forcefully-disconnect-a-vsphere-vm-console-session.html. Or if the console still takes keyboard input, you should be able to send ctrl+alt+del > task manager > kill chrome from there, even if you can't really see what's going on

yes, I have tried the second method as you suggested, but the screen resolution still does not get back and I tried to edit the Windows resolution (the remote host), but it is locked.

And after reboot and reboot, I found that the option is unlocked, and after edited, the resolution is back. Anyway, thanks for your help.
